# How to hide a field from a specific profile?

Tags: profile, field-level-security, access, visibility

I have a Pipeline object, in which I have a Members text box that I need to hide from Sales users.

I have made the configuration as shown:

[image: Field-level security]

[image: Field accessibility]

However, when I login as a Sales user, I still see the Members text box.

Are there any other settings I need to change?

Comment: Do you use standard layout or is it a custom page?

Comment: On standard layout, its not possible that field can be visible even when FLS is hidden. Can you re-check that you are logging through the correct user that has the same TH Sales profile for which FLS is set to not visible?

Comment: Did you check for any additional permission sets assigned to that user?

Comment: Correct said, Permission set might have the access to that field and that can be a possible reason that field is visible.

Comment: @RajeshVarmaMudunuri thank you, I found the problem, it is indeed caused by a permission set.

Comment: @ohseekay glad you found the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there was ever a permission issue, the first place i look for would be profile. If everything looks good on profile i look for assigned permission sets on the user detail page where you can find all the siigned permission sets for that user. Because permission sets can grant additional permission that are not part of their original profile.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Rajesh who pointed out that it could be due to other permission sets. I checked and indeed there was a permission set assigned to the sales user, that also granted access to that members field.

Since I wanted all other permissions associated with that set, what I did was to clone that permission set, and then remove the members field from the cloned set, then assign this altered clone set to the sales user.